# Responsive Design - All measuring units relative? What measuring units to use?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive web-page that utilizes a baseline grid for layout. The unit used for font-sizing is rem with a px fallback.
When is comes to defining margins, paddings, widths and heights, what unit should I use? Of course it is really tempting to use px, but is this a bad practice? What when a user zooms in?

I've also read that percentage values are the way to go for responsive design, but IMO it's really hard to use a rem grid while switching to another measuring unit.

In addition, I took a look at the HTML/CSS of some well known responsive sites made by professionals and even they use some px values, which really really irritates me.

Comment: http://blog.cloudfour.com/the-ems-have-it-proportional-media-queries-ftw/, http://kyleschaeffer.com/user-experience/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/.  It is common to see designers clinging to px because it is "easier" in their mind.

Comment: Please note that my question was not focused on font size rather than padding, margin, width and height.

Comment: Padding/margin *should* be relative to the font size.  A 10px margin is going to look unnatural user who views the page at 1em=30px, but will look perfectly natural to a user viewing the page at 1em=16px.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, flexing is far more indicated for responsive designs. You can learn a lot at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex (please, avoid W3Schools as a learning base).

Answer (score 0):

Though it would be nice if the ch unit were standardized, you can do some pretty good work just using em.